# Implemention of indoor posistion using Bluetooth 5.1

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-low-energy, tracking

I see how Bluetooth 5.1 is going to explode once released commercially. However when I watch the videos on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c3XqbEKmNcM) and how these companies are tracking these BLE 5.1 devices and how accurately it is, I do not see them showing the receiver, where the magic happens.

Has anyone had insight on how I can implement my own receiver to track these BLE 5.1 tags?

I have read the plethora of theory (such as [Bluetooth Indoor Positioning](https://www.u-blox.com/en/technologies/bluetooth-indoor-positioning), [Applications for Bluetooth 5.1 Direction Finding](https://www.silabs.com/products/wireless/learning-center/bluetooth/bluetooth-direction-finding#:%7E:text=The%20Bluetooth%205.1%20specification%20enhances,achieve%20sub%2Dmeter%20location%20accuracy.) and [Bluetooth Direction Finding](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Low-power-short-range-wireless/Direction-finding)) that clearly says in a theoretical manner how to track these tags by using the Angle of arrival method. However, there is no mention on how to practically go on about this. Such as what receiver chip do I use to track the BLE tag, how do I even start with the code/software...

A Bluetooth 5.1 [chip](https://www.nordicsemi.com/-/media/Software-and-other-downloads/Product-Briefs/nRF52811-product-brief.pdf?la=en&hash=1129A2206F346E11F55027991080095590A58B27)

Comment: please post links to any relevant documentation that you have found

Comment: for starters, the youtube video you are talking about ... if you have any manufacturer documents, then please include those

Comment: @jsotola i have added what you requested

Comment: Note carefully the statement in your first link, "***Using a constellation of multi-antenna anchors**, Bluetooth direction finding can be used to triangulate the precise location of a mobile device or tag within the covered indoor environment.*" It's not that you'll be able to use your phone on its own to track your keys. The [Coronavirus Contact Tracing: Evaluating The
Potential Of Using Bluetooth Received Signal
Strength For Proximity Detection](https://www.scss.tcd.ie/Doug.Leith/pubs/bluetooth_rssi_study.pdf) by Trinity College Dublin is worth a read.

Comment: @Transistor after some more reading yesterday, I get BLE 5.1 requires an antenna array at the receiver to detect the phase shifts of the incoming BLE signal. However is this any different than another RF direction finding device? What I am thinking is it is similar but the only difference is the frequency that is used.

Comment: I don't know enough to comment. I was asked in work to comment on the Irish Covid Tracker apps because we felt we were getting false positives. The study points out some of the problems with the technique. In the first half of the year there were several naive questions on the topic by folks inventing alarm devices. My understanding of the RSSI is that it's as much about signal quality (collisions, etc.) as actual signal strength. The study article shows that the signal strength is not calibrated and varies during frequency hopping.

Comment: what do you mean by 5.1 released commercially?  Its been out and were on 5.3 now. I work for a chip manufacturer that i wont name, and our BLE hardware can do AoA though our stack does not support it. But like you implied this is no different than doing it with any other RF based protocol at all, this is just BLE officially supporting it but its not anything inherent to BLE